# Select something where ID is "random"

Tags: php, mysql

I already searched for random ID. It seems I HAVE to select a random row? I don't quite understand it yet.

What I want to do is to select `tid`, `preis` from the stickythread from a random ID or row.

```
$sql="SELECT tid,preis FROM stickythread WHERE id=1";
```

Is there a simple way to get a random ID from 1 to 3, without changing to much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin that you mean:

```
select tid, preis 
from stickythread 
where id between 1 and 3 
order by rand() limit 1
```

The query filters on `id` between `1` and `3`, then `order by rand()` shuffles the results, and `limit 1` keeps the first row only.

Comment: Yes it is. I was not familiar with "between". Is it really so easy? I will test it, thank you.